# Sort by name attribute

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli

`companies` and `ships` both have a `name` attribute. But I don't understand how I can use `sortProperties` in this code:

**app/controllers/index.js**

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Controller.extend({
  selectedCompany: null,

  companies: function(){
    var model = this.get('model.companies');
    return model;
  }.property(),

  ships: function(){
    var model = this.get('model.ships');
    return model;
  }.property()
});
```

**app/routes/index.js**

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return {
      companies: this.store.find('company'),
      ships: this.store.find('ship')
    };
  }
});
```

How can I sort `companies` and `ships` by the `name` attribute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `sortBy` function. Like this:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Controller.extend({
  selectedCompany: null,

  sortedCompanies: function(){
    var model = this.get('model.companies').sortBy('name');
    return model;
  }.property('model.companies'),

  sortedShips: function(){
    var model = this.get('model.ships').sortBy('name');
    return model;
  }.property('model.ships')
});
```

Remember to put the property you observe into the `.property()` otherwise it's cache won't be invalidated when the model changes.